# c++ macro that removes parentheses

Tags: c++, macros

Suppose I have something like this somewhere in my .cpp code

```
name(min,max)
```

Can I write a macro?

```
#define GET_NAME(A) //transforms name(min,max) -> name;
```

And macro?

```
#define GET_RANGE(A) // transforms name(min,max) -> std::pair<T,N>(min,max);
```

Usage shall be like this

```
GET_NAME(r(0,255)) -> r
GET_RANGE(r(0,255)) -> std::pair<int,int>(0,255)
```

The real goal is to provide something like this

```
#ifndef PIXEL_PIXEL_HPP
#define PIXEL_PIXEL_HPP

#include <ostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T, unsigned int N>
union Pixel;

#define DECLARE_PIXEL(NAME, T, N, ...)                                                  \
template<>                                                                              \
union Pixel<T,N> {                                                                      \
    static const int SIZE = N;\
    T args[N];                                                                          \
    struct{                                                                                 \
        T __VA_ARGS__;\
    };\
                                                                          \
    Pixel() = default;                                                                  \
    Pixel(std::initializer_list<T> l) { std::move(l.begin(),l.end(),args); };            \
    Pixel(const Pixel<T,N>& other) = default;                                           \
    Pixel(Pixel<T,N>&& other) = default;                                                \
    T operator[](unsigned int i) const{                                                 \
        return args[i];\
    }                                                                                   \
    T& operator[](unsigned int i) {                                                     \
        return args[i];\
    }\
    bool operator==(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const{                                           \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                     \
            if(args[i] != rhs[i]) {                                               \
                return false;                                                           \
            }                                                                           \
        }                                                                               \
        return true;                                                                    \
    };                                                                                  \
    bool operator!=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const{                                           \
        return !(*this == rhs);                                                       \
    };                                                                                   \
    bool operator<(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const{                                            \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                     \
            if(args[i] >= rhs[i]) {                                                     \
                return false;\
            }\
        }                                                                               \
        return true;\
    };                                                                                  \
    bool operator>(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const{                                            \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                    \
            if(args[i] <= rhs[i]) {                                                \
                return false;\
            }\
        }                                                                               \
        return true;\
    };                                                                                 \
    bool operator<=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const{                                           \
        return !(*this > rhs);\
    };                                                                                  \
    bool operator>=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const{                                           \
        return !(*this < rhs);\
    };                                                                                  \
    Pixel<T,N>& operator=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) = default;                             \
    Pixel<T,N>& operator=(Pixel<T,N>&& rhs) = default;                                  \
    Pixel<T,N> operator*(T scalar) const{                                                 \
        Pixel<T,N> result;                                                              \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                    \
            result[i] = static_cast<T>(args[i] * scalar); \
        }                                                                               \
        return result;\
    };                                                                                  \
    friend Pixel<T,N> operator*(T scalar, const Pixel<T,N>& rhs){                    \
        return rhs * scalar;\
    }\
    Pixel<T,N> operator*(const Pixel<T,N>& other) const {                                     \
        Pixel<T,N> result;\
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                    \
            result[i] = static_cast<T>(args[i] * other[i]);\
        }                                                                               \
        return result;\
    };\
    Pixel<T,N> operator/(T scalar) const {                                          \
        return (*this) * (1/scalar);\
    };                                                                                  \
    friend Pixel<T,N> operator/(T scalar, const Pixel<T,N>& pixel) {                                          \
        return pixel / scalar;\
    }\
    Pixel<T,N> operator/(const Pixel<T,N>& other) const {                               \
        Pixel<T,N> result;                                                              \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                    \
            result[i] = static_cast<T>(args[i] / other[i]);\
        }                                                                               \
        return result;\
    };\
    Pixel<T,N> operator+(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const {                                       \
        Pixel<T,N> result;                                                              \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                    \
            result[i] = static_cast<T>(args[i] + rhs[i]); \
        }                                                                               \
        return result;\
    };                                                                                  \
    Pixel<T,N> operator-(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) const {                                 \
        Pixel<T,N> result;                                                              \
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {                                                    \
            result[i] = static_cast<T>(args[i] - rhs[i]);\
        }                                                                               \
        return result;                                                                  \
    }                                                                                   \
    Pixel<T,N>& operator +=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs)  {                              \
        *this = *this + rhs;                                                            \
        return *this;\
    }                                                                                   \
    Pixel<T,N>& operator -=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) {                                    \
        *this = *this - rhs;                                                            \
        return *this;\
    }                                                                                   \
    Pixel<T,N>& operator *=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) {                                     \
        *this = *this * rhs;                                                            \
        return *this;\
    }                                                                                   \
    Pixel<T,N>& operator /=(const Pixel<T,N>& rhs) {                                    \
        *this = *this / rhs;                                                            \
        return *this;\
    }\
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Pixel<T,N>& pixel) {        \
        for(const auto& elem : pixel.args){                                                   \
            os<<elem << " ";                                                     \
        }                                                                               \
        return os;\
    }                                                                                   \
    \
};                                                                                      \
using NAME = Pixel<T,N>;                                                                \


DECLARE_PIXEL(RGB, int, 3,r(0,255), g(0,255), b(0,255))

DECLARE_PIXEL(ARGB, float, 4, a(0,1), r(0,1), g(0,1), b(0,1))

#undef DECLARE_PIXEL

#endif //PIXEL_PIXEL_HPP
```

And there will be some new pixel types like HSL too.
Note that the range part of the variable is going to stored as a static vector of pairs, whilest the name of the variable will be stored in a struct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224826/discussion-on-question-by-hrant-nurijanyan-c-macro-that-removes-parentheses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Note: I rewrote this answer after it was accepted to make it much simpler.</sup>

I suggest not using a single macro or a `union` for this but instead add accessors to the specific elements in the array.

You can implement the basic member functions in your `Pixel` class template and inherit from `rgb` and `argb` classes that holds the array and implements accessors.

Example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Pixel : public T {
    static constexpr size_t SIZE = sizeof(T);

    // only methods here, no non-static member variables

    // iterators
    auto cbegin() const { return this->arr.cbegin(); }
    auto cend() const { return this->arr.cend(); }
    auto begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    auto end() const { return cend(); }
    auto begin() { return this->arr.begin(); }
    auto end() { return this->arr.end(); }

    // an example of a function adding one Pixel to another
    Pixel& operator+=(const Pixel& rhs) {
        auto rit = rhs.begin();
        for(auto& v : this->arr) v += *rit++;
        return *this;
    }
};

// make the functions returning a new object into free functions
template<typename T>
Pixel<T> operator+(const Pixel<T>& a, const Pixel<T>& b) {
    Pixel rv = a;
    rv += b;
    return rv;
}

// streaming the values in a Pixel<T>
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Pixel<T>& p) {
    os << '{';
    auto it = p.cbegin();
    if constexpr(sizeof(*it) == 1) os << static_cast<int>(*it);
    else os << *it;

    for(++it; it != p.cend(); ++it) {
        os << ',';
        if constexpr(sizeof(*it) == 1) os << static_cast<int>(*it);
        else os << *it;        
    }
    return os << '}';
}
```

Then define `rgb` and `argb` with accessors:

```
struct rgb {
    std::uint8_t& r() { return arr[0]; }
    std::uint8_t& g() { return arr[1]; }
    std::uint8_t& b() { return arr[2]; }

    std::uint8_t r() const { return arr[0]; }
    std::uint8_t g() const { return arr[1]; }
    std::uint8_t b() const { return arr[2]; }

    std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> arr;  
};

struct argb {
    float& a() { return arr[0]; }
    float& r() { return arr[1]; }
    float& g() { return arr[2]; }
    float& b() { return arr[3]; }

    float a() const { return arr[0]; }
    float r() const { return arr[1]; }
    float g() const { return arr[2]; }
    float b() const { return arr[3]; }

    std::array<float, 4> arr;  
};
```

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    Pixel<rgb> x {{126,127,128}};
    Pixel<rgb> y {{129,128,127}};
    Pixel<rgb> z = x + y;

    Pixel<argb> foo {{1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f}};
    Pixel<argb> bar {{1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f}};

    foo += bar;

    std::cout << z << '\n';
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(z) << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
{255,255,255}
{2.2,4.4,6.6,8.8}
3
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a macro cannot do that. If you are willing to change a syntax slightly, for example, instead of `r(0,255)` write `(r)((0,255))` or `(r,(0,255))` then this is doable. See for example the [Boost Preprocessor library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) documentation.

You will not be able to write `T __VA_ARGS__;` directly, you will need to iterate over the arguments instead (Boost Preprocessor can do that as well).

Having said that, whatever the question is, a macro is almost never a good answer.